# slds modal in inline visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, slds, lightning-out, inline-visualforce

I'm using lightning out to put my lwc in classic record page. Everything works, except the slds modal open within the hight of inline vf page rather than as an overlay.

[image]

In lightning, this works perfectly

[image]

How can I fix it?